BTRFS Filesystem creation failing on SUSE Linux (SLES 15 SP4 Azure) if 3 devices are passed as arguments
I try to create a BTRFS filesystem with 3 devices getting an error on the 3rd argument, saying

failed to scan device

although the device is a newly attached clean disk. This happens even if I rearrange the order in the BTRFS fs creation command. However creating BTRFS file system using one device and then adding the remaining 2 devices works.
OS Version: SLES 15 SP4 for SAP Database on Azure
saphana2:/ # sudo mkfs.btrfs -n 4096 -d single -m single /dev/sdf /dev/sde /dev/sdd
btrfs-progs v5.14 
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

Label:              (null)
UUID:               653ebec6-2489-42f2-8793-ed6e25b302d9
Node size:          4096
Sector size:        4096
Filesystem size:    256.00GiB
Block group profiles:
  Data:             single            8.00MiB
  Metadata:         single            8.00MiB
  System:           single            4.00MiB
SSD detected:       no
Zoned device:       no
Incompat features:  extref, skinny-metadata
Runtime features:   
Checksum:           crc32c
Number of devices:  2
Devices:
   ID        SIZE  PATH
    1   128.00GiB  /dev/sdf
    2   128.00GiB  /dev/sde

ERROR: device scan failed on '/dev/sdd': Invalid argument

Even if I rearrange the order of devices to put /dev/sdf in the end, throwing the same error.
saphana2:/var/log/lucidity # sudo mkfs.btrfs -f -n 4096 -d single -m single /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
btrfs-progs v5.14 
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

Label:              (null)
UUID:               d54dfaf8-08fc-46fb-90fe-a24dd83bc414
Node size:          4096
Sector size:        4096
Filesystem size:    384.00GiB
Block group profiles:
  Data:             single            8.00MiB
  Metadata:         single            8.00MiB
  System:           single            4.00MiB
SSD detected:       no
Zoned device:       no
Incompat features:  extref, skinny-metadata
Runtime features:   
Checksum:           crc32c
Number of devices:  2
Devices:
   ID        SIZE  PATH
    1   256.00GiB  /dev/sdd
    2   128.00GiB  /dev/sde

ERROR: device scan failed on '/dev/sdf': Invalid argument

However if I create BTRFS with one device and then add the remaining 2 devices using BTRFS device add, it's working:
saphana2:/ # sudo mkfs.btrfs -n 4096 -d single -m single /dev/sdf 
saphana2:/ # sudo btrfs device add /dev/sdd /tmpbtrfs
saphana2:/ # sudo btrfs device add /dev/sde /tmpbtrfs

Request help on mitigating this.
